# Form action URL not being found

Tags: java, javascript, forms, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am trying to handle input from a basic HTML form in Java. However, whenever I click the submit button on the form I get this error: "The requested URL /formHandler was not found on this server."

Following are the form and the Java servlet, both of which live in the same directory, along with all the other files for this site. Any ideas why the servlet is not being found?

**FORM**

```
<form method="post" action="formHandler">
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input name="name" defaultValue="name"/><br/>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input name="email" defaultValue="email"/><br/>
                <label for="details">Further Details or Comments</label><br/>
                <input name="details" defaultValue="details"/><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**SERVLET**

```
@WebServlet("/formHandler")
public class FormHandler extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String details = request.getParameter("details");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String htmlRespone = "<html>";
        htmlRespone += "<h2>Thank you " + name + ", a confirmation email will be sent to " + email + " shortly.</h2>";
        htmlRespone += "</html>";

        writer.println(htmlRespone);

    } 
}
```

Comment: What's the root context of your web application?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I'm sorry, but I don't know what that means

Comment: I'm using mamp to serve it, if that's what you mean. it's serving the parent directory of these two files on localhost